# Web service load test test using visual studio 2010

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2010, load-testing

1. How to write custom web service load test:

   - All my web services has byte[] (byte array) as input and output.
   - Internally we have xml as input and ouuput which we encrypt and decrypt in custom way.
   - I checked that I can write down the custom validatation rule using visual studio. But can i also customize the input. (i.e. I pick the input load data from csv/xml and perform the required encrypt/decript before sending the the server)
2. Does the web service load testing supports the https communication?

Thanks and Regards,
Hardik

Comment: How do you test your services? Are you using `Web Performance Tests` or `Unit Tests`?

Comment: I want to create tests using Web Performance Test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First, you have to create the `Web Performance Test` that will be used by the `Load Test`. Check these [walkthroughs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337591.aspx) which will help you to find out:

   - How to change the code of a recorded `Web Performance Test`
   - How to data bind a `Web Performance Test`
   - How to add validation rules to a `Web Performance Test`
   - Also I believe that this [guide](http://vsptqrg.codeplex.com/) will be very helpful to troubleshoot any possible issue
2. As far as I know there is no restriction on tesing HTTPS services through a `Web Performance Test`

*I suggest to check the option of `Unit Test` as well. I have tried it and in my opinion they are more easy to create them. Of course, this is your choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing direction. Can we use the Unit test for load testing? I have started using the Visual Studio test recently so please forgive my ignorance!

Comment: To be honest I haven't worked with `Web Performance Tests` too much so I don't know if is better or not to use them instead of `Unit Tests`. The way I chose to do the `Load Testing` of our Web Services was through `Unit Tests`. Each `Unit Test` calls the Web Services through a [**client**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx.aspx). Then I use these simple `Unit Tests` to create any type of `Load Test` I need. For me it it was more easy that way.

Comment: Creating Unit test using client would be easy for me (btw. great suggestion, thanks) and I tried that just now (Test project -> rightclick -> new Test -> Basoc unit test). Am I correct here? But the problem is how to use that into load test? I can not see the newly created unit test in the Test Mix dialog. I have ckecked [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms318554.aspx) also. CAn you point out what do i miss? I have also checked the link [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms318554.aspx)

Comment: It sounds like you don't have `Build` your Solution yet. All unit tests are available to use them in Load Tests :).

Comment: I have tried building the solution. Still not in the Load Mix list. Can you check if i am addign the unit test correctly? I am adding by ( project -> rightclick -> new Test -> Basoc unit test).

Comment: Yes it the right way to do it, but I cannot debug your code from here :). Check again this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff355993.aspx).

Comment: I can see the unit tests in list now. I have deleted old unit tests and created new. Don't know what was wrong. Tommorow I will create a proof of concept for my actual work. Thanks a lot for support without this i must have lost somewhere.